# redirect sound over x11 session by pulse-audio

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, pulse-audio

I am trying pass over X11 session.we can implement with pulse audio.I Google and i tried many configuration.still iam not able to redirect sound over X session.Any one can  help me out with proper client/server configuration of pulse audio.I am using Ubuntu as server and my embedded system as client.